# How to stop read.table from rounding numbers with different degrees of precision in R?

Tags: r, digits, read.table

I am trying to import a text file containing latitudes and longitudes into `R`, which all have different degrees of precision (i.e. points after the decimal).  When I try to use `read.table`, the data imports but cuts off at 5 decimal places.  Is there a way around this?  I have not found anything in the documentation that worked.

An example of data from the text file:

```
35.326354762000001 91.761496755
35.512443542 92.356571172
35.319078183999999 92.233513991
35.315654623 91.912230315
35.293864976999998 92.442997238
35.435569418 92.231860894
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

`read.table` doesn't round (unless you provide more than ~16 digits behind the comma), but indeed the precision to which the answer is *printed* may be controlled with `options(digits=[n])`

Comment: Ah! Got it, thank you!  Is there a way to change the formatting to display more digits by default?  I haven't found one (in RStudio)

Comment: You could add a line in your .Rprofile file

Answer (score 0):

You could try `options(digits()`, like so:

```
options(digits=5)
35.326354762000001
#[1] 35.326
options(digits=20)
35.326354762000001
#[1] 35.326354762000001
```

Comment: The input values, however, have different number of digits.  So when I try to use that technique I get errors.

Comment: What does the errors say?

Answer (score 0):

As pointed our by @Mark,  it's just a display issue. The read.table is treating the 2nd column as a numeric. You can force read it as a char as follows to display all digits while printing the data frame.  Say you have the data in the file test.txt... The following will generate the desired output

```
df <- read.table("test.txt", sep=" ",colClasses = c("character", "character"))
```