# R map plotting issue

Tags: r, maps, precision

I'm simply plotting lat/longs from a file onto a map in R. I'm having some issues as the points I plot are displayed in roughly the correct area - but not accurate enough for me. I don't know if this is my code, the google map, or the resultion of the lat/longs? I think I've eliminated the latter (see below).

Code:

```
library (ggmap)
library (gdata)

whitelee_boundary <- c(left = -4.6, bottom = 55.5, right = -3.8, top = 55.8)
map2 <- get_stamenmap(whitelee_boundary, zoom = 12, maptype = "toner-lite")
ggmap(map2)

df <- read.table("WhiteleeLatLong.txt", header = FALSE)
lat=df[1]
lon=df[2]
lati=as.numeric(unlist(lat))
long= as.numeric(unlist(lon))

points(lati, long, col = "blue", cex = 1.0)
```

which results in blue circles plotted in a very tight(incorrect) geographical range

[image: blue circles plotted in a very tight(incorrect) geographical range]

I then attempted to error check the points by manually displaying:

```
points(55.7, -4.4, col = "blue", cex = 1.0)
```

This results in no point being visibly added (making me think that this is my code or google map accuracy).

I originally thought this was a precision issue in read.table or numeric conversion, and have already consulted:

[How to stop read.table from rounding numbers with different degrees of precision in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31383951/how-to-stop-read-table-from-rounding-numbers-with-different-degrees-of-precision)

[as.numeric() removes decimal places in R, how to change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29880210/as-numeric-removes-decimal-places-in-r-how-to-change)

However it seems that the rounding is only aesthetic, and the numbers are stored with the requisite precision.

Apologies in advance - its been a very long time since my last coding task!

EDIT: When I command

```
points(-4.4, 55.7, col = "blue", cex = 1.0)
```

THe output is (ignore large circles):

[Plot appears on map but not in correct location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6ec8.jpg)

Comment: Can you share a few of your long and lat points as they are?

Comment: sure: 55.68918453 -4.356793868

Comment: Your points call is wrong: switch the x and y (55.7 is a lat or y; -4.4 is a long or x), i.e. `points(-4.4, 55.7, col = "blue", cex = 1.0)`

Comment: It's not a question of accuracy, then! 2 or 3 decimal places is more than enough for this scale map. TBH, 8 decimal places is probably spurious accuracy, anyway. What are the minimum and maximum of your longitude and latitude coordinates?

Comment: Thx Phil- Max/ mins : 55.71402019
55.6552228
and -4.362110752
-4.183033069

Comment: I tried the x/y switch - point is being plotted but not in the right place. See edit to original question for detail.

Comment: I don't know how you're using `points()` to add to a ggplot. When I try that, I get an error: `Error in plot.xy(xy.coords(x, y), type = type, ...) : 
  plot.new has not been called yet`. But if you name you say `my_map = ggmap(map2)` and then add `my_map + geom_point(y = 55.7, x = -4.4, col = "blue", size = 1.0)`, the dot appears in just the right place. So overall **I can't reproduce what you are plotting, and it seems like a typo to try to use base plotting command with ggplot, so I'm voting to close.**

Comment: OK - I appreciate the feedback

Comment: I think to help further you really need to provide a few points from `WhiteleeLatLong.txt`, i.e. provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).